# Can't get a very simple Keras model to learn

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've just started teaching myself Keras and I'm building trivial challenges to solve. I have managed to get off the ground and have managed to train a few simple models. However, there is a strange situation where a model trains well if I apply a simple linear transformation to the inputs but not otherwise. Here is the code that I'm using. One of these learns and the other doesn't. The aim of the model is to learn to figure out if someone is an adult given the year and month of birth.

```
from random import random
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense


X = [[1980 + int(39*random()), int(12*random())] for _ in range(0, 5000)]
y = [1 if (12 * (2020 - x[0]) + (5 - x[1])) > 216 else 0 for x in X]
# X = [[12 * (2020 -x[0]) + (5 - x[1])] for x in X]

X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)

model = Sequential()
layer = Dense(1, input_dim=2, kernel_initializer='random_normal', activation='sigmoid')
model.add(layer)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X, y, epochs=1000, batch_size=100)
```

Now this model does not seem to learn at all. The loss remains stuck at around 0.68 throughout.

Things don't improve even if I rescale the inputs using:

```
X = [[x[0] / 1000.0, x[1] / 12.0] for x in X]
```

However, if I uncomment the line in the code above and change the input dimension of the layer to 1, the model converges very nicely. Shouldn't the current model converge as well. I can't see what I'm doing wrong here.

As a clarification, the input here is basically the year and month of birth. We're assuming that we are checking if a person is an adult in May, 2020.

--

Edit:

I seem to have found the answer, thanks to @catalina's point about "variety". Since the input variables were all integers, there were only a few actual examples for the system to learn from. For a gradient to be defined nicely, you'd need more points on the surface being learned. So, in this case, if I change the relevant part of my code to the following:

```
X = [[1980 + int(39*random()), int(12*random())] for _ in range(0, 5000)]

# adding random noise to create "variety"
X = [[x[0] + random(), x[1] + random()] for x in X]
y = [1 if (12 * (2020 - x[0]) + (5 - x[1])) > 216 else 0 for x in X]

# approximately centering the inputs 
X = [[x[0] - 2002, x[1] - 6] for x in X]
```

The model converges beautifully. I'm still a little unclear why the centering was necessary (without it, it does not converge). I suspect that is because the gradient would be far too flat at the point where the weights start out, making it hard to find a direction to move in.

P.S. - I absolutely get that this is not the right use-case for an NN. But my attempt right now is to understand the underlying mechanics to the point where everything I do flows from first principles. For example, the fact that x[1] is "noise" and should be dropped altogether, as suggested by a member, turns out to be not correct in this context.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I see how you generated your model but I did not see your dataset and some visualization of it. Therefore what I say is a general statement, based on my knowledge and my experience. I can be sure only after testing and having acess to concrete results.

Generally speaking, when you have good results with a linear model and less good with a neural network, the issue might be that the data does not have a very great degree of variety. A neural network works well if you have a gerat amount of data AND a much variety. Otherwise, it is better to use a linear model as the NN is not the approriate solution.

In your case, if you wish to try a neural network I suggest you find and download some open data (minimum 5000 samples I may say) and run your NN on it, rather than generate your data as you do.

You should also read some documentation on Neural Networks, check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) for a start.

I see you have only two features. I suggest you add some more features, let us say by transforming the features you have. That will add to variety.

Comment: Thanks Catalina. I understand your point about variety. However, I did manage to get a single neuron to learn a linear model quite well. Further, as I point out in the question, if I take the appropriate linear combination of x[0] and x[1] and provide that as the input, the model fits quite well. I'm not sure why that happens if variety is the issue.

The reason I'm doing this exercise is to build my understanding ground up, given that I understand the dataset itself very well (it is very simple).

Could it be that the cross entropy loss surface is too flat when spread over two inputs?

Comment: I just realised the model is finding it hard to converge even if I change the learning from "is adult" to "age in months" and use a mean square error loss. I guess I need to study this more. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, what do you mean by linear model? Linear activation function? Neural networks are not linear by definition. When talking about linear model I thought you meant machine learning algorithms. PS: I saw you accepted my answer and then rejected it, is it so? What hapenned?

Comment: By linear model, I mean trying to learn something like:

Y = ax1 + bx2 + c

Actually, if you have a single neuron (as in Keras. A real neuron would have a 0/1 output), with no activation function, and you use sgd with a mean squered error loss, it should be able to fit this quite well. It is true that there is absolutely no reason to use an NN to do this. But it's really a question of whether it ought to work. And I believe it ought to.

I have "unaccepted" right now as I explore if that is indeed the correct explanation for my problem. Really appreciate you taking the time though!

Comment: If it works well with SDG then why do you want to use a NN? NN are not the magical solution for every problem,a and some problems might be solved better with a machine learning algorithm (NN is a deep learning algorithm). Keep in mind that a NN will consume more memory on your computer so using ML will help saving memory and do things in a ligher way from the IT point of view.

Comment: I would like the persons who downvoted my answer to argue why they did that. Bring your arguments, please.I am open to discussion as discussion is always a way of improvement.

Comment: your point about variety turned out to be exactly the problem. I have edited my question to add the resolution as well.

As for using this framework when SGD works is because this is the best SGD implementation I have and I wish to cement my understanding of problems that can cause SGD to get thrown off. As in this case, a lack of variety. Also, apologies I don't have enough rep to upvote your answer.

Comment: Glad to have been helpful!

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues, like the capacity of the network being too small, hard thresholding to make a really hard loss surface, etc.

But, the main point I found was the highly skewed inputs for the first case.

`X = [[1980 + int(39*random()), int(12*random())] for _ in range(0, 5000)]`

The two values in the input are extremely skewed, one being more than 150 times than the other one.

There are other fixes to make the network converge but the most simple one being, just re-scaling the inputs.

For example, the following input also converges easily.

`X = [[1980 + int(39*random()), 1000 + int(12*random())] for _ in range(0, 5000)]`

The only thing I changed was the range of the input.

Update:

After your comment, I just plotted the data and realized your x[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bM9fP.png) is pure noise to the data which is completely destroying the predictions.

```
plt.plot(X[:100,0])
plt.plot(X[:100,1])
plt.plot(y[:100])
plt.legend(['x0', 'x1', 'y'])
plt.show()
```

A person's age has nothing to do with the month of birth, as you can see in the graph, the month is completely adding pure noise to the predictions. If a person is an adult or not only depends on the birth year, the birth month would be a complete noise to the model, for such a simple model, it has no way to eliminate that noise hence such poor performance.

**But, if you increase your network capacity with proper scaling you can technically make the model memorize the samples.**

[image]

Just to give some basic idea,

```
cnt = 0
idx = 0
for x in X:
  if x[1] == 1:
    print(x)
    print(y[idx])
    cnt += 1
    if cnt == 100:
      break
  idx += 1
```

```
[1987, 1]
1
[1986, 1]
1
[2001, 1]
1
[1983, 1]
1
[2011, 1]
0
[2003, 1]
0
[1990, 1]
1
[2016, 1]
0
[1980, 1]
1
[2002, 1]
1
[1987, 1]
1
[1996, 1]
1
[1997, 1]
1
[1984, 1]
1
[2005, 1]
0
[2016, 1]
0
[1987, 1]
1
[1984, 1]
1
[1986, 1]
1
[1990, 1]
1
[1983, 1]
1
[2006, 1]
0
[2018, 1]
0
[2012, 1]
0
[1992, 1]
1
[1992, 1]
1
[2012, 1]
0
[2013, 1]
0
[1988, 1]
1
[2014, 1]
0
[1992, 1]
1
[2018, 1]
0
[2013, 1]
0
[2006, 1]
0
[1984, 1]
1
[1992, 1]
1
[2003, 1]
0
[1991, 1]
1
[1993, 1]
1
[2001, 1]
1
[2015, 1]
0
[2013, 1]
0
[1997, 1]
1
[2000, 1]
1
[2011, 1]
0
[2000, 1]
1
[1987, 1]
1
[1985, 1]
1
[1983, 1]
1
[1999, 1]
1
[2015, 1]
0
[2018, 1]
0
[1996, 1]
1
[1987, 1]
1
[1997, 1]
1
[2015, 1]
0
[1982, 1]
1
[1995, 1]
1
[2016, 1]
0
[1986, 1]
1
[2009, 1]
0
[2009, 1]
0
[2007, 1]
0
[2009, 1]
0
[2013, 1]
0
[1998, 1]
1
[1994, 1]
1
[2011, 1]
0
[1997, 1]
1
[2004, 1]
0
[2015, 1]
0
[2015, 1]
0
[1983, 1]
1
[1984, 1]
1
[2014, 1]
0
[1988, 1]
1
[2008, 1]
0
[2010, 1]
0
[2009, 1]
0
[2004, 1]
0
[2002, 1]
1
[1991, 1]
1
[2001, 1]
1
[1982, 1]
1
[2011, 1]
0
[2002, 1]
1
[2013, 1]
0
[2001, 1]
1
[2000, 1]
1
[1998, 1]
1
[1999, 1]
1
[2017, 1]
0
[2001, 1]
1
[1981, 1]
1
[1994, 1]
1
[2000, 1]
1
[2011, 1]
0
[1988, 1]
1
[1982, 1]
1
```

As you can see, it's pretty clear, even though the month is 1 for all of those data, only the year makes the label 1 or 0. the month has absolutely no effect on the data, it's useless. If month is high the label is 0 and vice-versa.

Comment: Thanks Zabir. But I don't think that's the issue. When you added 1000 to the second parameter, every person in the dataset effectively became an adult. So it naturally converges.

On the other hand, I rescaled the inputs by dividing x[0] by 1000 and x[1] by 12. That makes them about the same scale. And I still get a non-converging model.

Comment: Again, thanks. It is not absolute noise though. However, you are right it is only relevant when x[0] == 2002. In 2002, the x[1] being less than 5 makes the person an adult and at higher values, not.

If you see the commented line in the code, the exact relationship very much involves x[1]. I'm basically trying to understand why the model does not learn the linear combination that is required.

Comment: Zabir. Like I said, I agree that in almost all circumstances, the month is irrelevant. But in a few cases it is the deciding factor (as when x[0] is 2002). There, the label flips when x[1] > 5. But I see your point that the variable is adding very little value.

Comment: @ZabirAlNazi: Your question : "how the accepted answer shows more research effort?" deserves an answer and I shall answer gladly. The reflection provided in my answer is the result of years and years of professional training and working in ML and NLP field (and I am not counting here the time I spent at the University). It is not a research done only for this particular question and it certainly took much more than several hours. Hoping to having been helpful!